# Constant time appending and retrieval from the end with Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections, doubly-linked-list

So I need to use some structure like DoubleLinkedList I guess, but when I saw the implementation of the DLL in scala, seems it doesn't provide the efficient implementation for last() function or something else to have fast access to the end. Here is, what I saw in the implementation:

```
  def last: A = {
    var lst = head
    for (x <- this)
      lst = x
    lst
  }
```

it seems linear, doesn't it? maybe DLL should override this function, what do you think?

Comment: May you post a link to the source where you found this implementation?

Comment: I pressed ctrl-b in Intellij IDEA)

Comment: Why not use an IndexedSeq, which supports "constant-time or near constant-time element access and length computation"?

Comment: @dmitry it is [defined in list superclass](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.2/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableLike.scala#L454)

Comment: @fynn because it do not provide **constant append** from the end (see the title -- both access and retrieval desired)?

Comment: Seems you are right. Their version of DoubleLinkedList has no reference to the last element, as I recall, datastructure with O(1) addition to beginning/end is called Deque (double ended queue) and seems there is still no such in standard library. You may create pull request :)

Comment: `ListBuffer` keeps track of the last element, but does not give an efficient implementation for retrieval or removal (only appending). It should be easy to add the functionality to this class though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double linking in `DoubleLinkedListLike` only refers to going forward and backward along the list. There isn't a direct pointer to the end of the list.

If you only need fast access and update for the last element, you could use a `List` with reversed order. It depends on what other operations you need. Rolling your own DLL with last-pointer is quite simple, but if you just need a good performing ready structure, take a look at the immutable `Vector`. It has quasi-constant update and access (some log32 factor which is 'effectively' constant).

---

If you really want a mutable type, see [the official documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/concrete-mutable-collection-classes.html) for an overview and the capabilities. Namely see what the DLL is good for. Section "Mutable Lists" covers the case of fast append.

Comment: MutableList is what I wanted), thanks) But still, it is somewhat misleading that we do not have efficient implementation of the last element in DLL)